# Solr4.3 - Get Terms Frequency

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm tring to get terms frequency on Solr4.3 but it don't work.
I have tried with multivalue fields and not but it don't work with both.
I have read in this post ([SOLR term frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688459/solr-term-frequency)) that multivalue field not work with terms :(. It's true?.
This is my request:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=casa&qs=3&fl=*&mm=1&qf=name&defType=dismax&wt=xml&hl=true&terms=true&terms.fl=name
```

In schema.xml file I have this code:

```
<field name="id"            type="string"     indexed="true"    stored="true"    required="true" /> 
   <field name="name"           type="text"                         stored="true"    required="true"        termVectors="true"  termPositions="true"    termOffsets="true" /> 

   <field name="review"         type="text"       indexed="true"    stored="true"    multiValued="true"     termVectors="true"  termPositions="true"    termOffsets="true" /> 
   <field name="description"    type="text"       indexed="true"    stored="true"    multiValued="true"     termVectors="true"  termPositions="true"    termOffsets="true" /> 
   <field name="id_b"           type="text"       indexed="true"    stored="true"    multiValued="true"  />
   <field name="id_c"           type="text"       indexed="true"    stored="true"    multiValued="true"  />
```

Please, any suggests?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the addition of last-components with the search handler.

Following configuration worked fine for Solr 4.3

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <bool name="terms">true</bool>
        <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>terms</str>
    </arr>    
</requestHandler>
```

Sample Query `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=ipod&terms.fl=name` returned both the response and the terms.

Comment: use simply faceting on the content field, it will give the same result